# Why infinite expansions of basic functions and polynomial expansions use factorial in the denominator

Tags: real-analysis

I'm looking for a very basic applicable example of why in infinite series and other infinite expansions of basic/transcendental functions ($\log{x}$, $e^x$, $\sin{x}$, power series, etc) use factorials in the denominator. I'm trying to find out why many infinite expansions like $x^n/n!$ involve $1 \cdot 2, 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3, 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4, \&c$, in the denominator.
I appreciate any help.

Comment: The expansion of the logarithm doesn't use the factorial, right?

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\frac{x^n}{n!}$ behaves really nicely when differentiating: $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x^n}{n!}=\frac{nx^{n-1}}{n!}=\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$, so with each differentiation we get an expression of the same form.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the formula for the Taylor series:

$\sum_{n=0} ^ {\infty} \frac {f^{(n)}(a)}{n!} \, (x-a)^{n}$

As long as the derivatives don't grow as fast as the factorial, there will always be a factorial in the denominator.

You can think of the factorial coming about because the successive derivatives of $x^n$ are $nx^{n-1}$, $n\cdot(n-1)x^{n-2}$, $n\cdot(n-1)\cdot(n-2)x^{n-3}$, etc.

Comment: The queston is *why* are there factorials in Taylor series, I think...

Comment: Okay. The Binomial Theorem uses factorials as well without any derivatives and makes use of Pascal's Triangle. You can make polynomial expansions for any function, and they use factorials. But I need rigor or a proof as an example of how in application this works. Know of any good websites or books?

Comment: Well, the factorials come into play because, say, the fourth derivative of $x^4$ is $4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1$. This is related to the binomial theorem through the definition of the derivative: $\frac{d}{dx}{x^n}=lim\frac{(x+h)^n-x^n}{h}$. You can expand the $(x+h)^n$ using the binomial theorem.